# URLs on main page in article class

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, urls, url

I want to include URLs on my main page in the article class. I am using the following packages

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Test}

\date{} 

\maketitle

test: \url{https://test.test}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

When I compile the file I am getting the word "magenta" right before the url as follows:

[image]

I can't find anything related to this. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

All other links in the file are showing correctly.

Comment: show a small but *complete*  example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer added an example

Comment: this errors as the text is before \begin{document}. Please test your example before sending them and check for errors.

Comment: it works on my end. I am using Overleaf and it is generating the pdf

Comment: it errors, overleaf should show you a red error marker like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqRbb.png. Don't ignore such errors, they tell you that something is really wrong and this can affect the output as your own question shows.

Comment: In addition to Ulrikes comments, note that overleaf runs in a mode that attempts to autoresolve errors and always produce a pdf. It does this by making an educated guess. This guess is often wrong and then accumulates giving a totally wrong output. Sadly a lot of overleaf users tend to ignore the errors because it does produce a pdf. Now you know why you should never ignore errors. Hopefully one day overleaf will change their interface to make people more aware that there are errors and that they need to be fixed